# Python Web Scraping an element- try until it works, then wait, and try again

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, try-except

The code below runs perfectly, but after 10 seconds I get an exception (which says the element is not found), and thats because the element is getting refreshed. it takes less than 1 seconds to get refreshed.
So all I need to do, is wait when its getting refreshed, and then continue.

```
items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('box')

for item in items:
    while True:
        try:
            title = item.find_element_by_class_name('title').text
            break
        except:
            time.sleep(4)
            pass
```

I tried to solve it with try: except: but once it joins the except part, it gets stuck in the loop. How do we solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably have a if condition with `find_elements` like below :

```
for item in items:
  while True:
    try:
      if len(driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "title")) > 0:
        title = item.find_element_by_class_name('title').text
        break
      else:
        print("Elemennt could not be found")
    except NoSuchElementException as error:
      time.sleep(4)
      print("Something went wrong")
      pass
```

You may need this **import** :

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, WebDriverException, NoSuchElementException
```

Comment: it shows me this error 
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

on the line of title = item.find_element_by_class_name('title').text

Comment: @DisplayMoto : try the updated code above, should help you by past the issue.